# Once apply XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml

```
<root>
    <foo>Hello</foo>
    <bar>World</bar>
</root>
```

and template

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <div>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//bar" mode="inner" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
    <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar" mode="inner">
    <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
</xsl:template>
```

expect

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>World</span>
</div>
```

actual

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>World</span>
</div><span>World</span>
```

I do not have the possibility to block output of the block *bar*. This template is used elsewhere

```
<xsl:template match="bar" />
```

*-- edit --*

I can not override the root template (it's a different level of abstraction)

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

I can not block the use of a template *bar* as it is needed.

```
<root>
    <bar>World</bar>
</root>
```

expect

```
<span>World</span>
```

*-- real example --*

template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    version="1.0"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    media-type="text/html"
    encoding="utf-8"
    indent="yes"
/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="block[@place='main']"/>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block/page">
    <div class="page-second">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//block/news" mode="inner" />
        <div class="info">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block/news">
    <div class="clear" />
    <div class="news-block">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="article" />
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block/news" mode="inner">
    <div class="news-block">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{article/link}"><xsl:value-of select="article/title" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block/news/article">
    <li><a href="{link}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a></li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml 1

```
<root>
    <block place="main">
        <page>
            <title>Page title</title>
            <text>Page text</text>
        </page>
    </block>
    <block place="main">
        <news>
            <title>News title</title>
            <article>
                <title>Article 1 title</title>
                <link>/article-1/</link>
            </article>
            <article>
                <title>Article 2 title</title>
                <link>/article-2/</link>
            </article>
        </news>
    </block>
</root>
```

expect result 1

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="page-second">
    <div class="news-block">
        <h2>News title</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/article-1/">Article 1 title</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        Page text
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

xml 2

```
<root>
    <block place="main">
        <news>
            <title>News title</title>
            <article>
                <title>Article 1 title</title>
                <link>/article-1/</link>
            </article>
            <article>
                <title>Article 2 title</title>
                <link>/article-2/</link>
            </article>
        </news>
    </block>
</root>
```

result 2

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="clear" />
<div class="news-block">
    <h2>News title</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/article-1/">Article 1 title</a></li>
        <li><a href="/article-2/">Article 2 title</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbx I get the wanted output but you will need to decide whether you want to block the output of `bar` elements in the default mode or whether you want to transform `bar` elements in that mode, having two templates with the same match pattern and priority is an error from which the XSLT processor might recover by choosing the latter template.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Having two templates with the same match pattern should never be a solution.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I wrote that I can not block the use of the default template, as it is used elsewhere

Comment: using a parameter in the 'bar-template' (eg `<xsl:param name="execute" />`) could solve the problem. A simple if could check if the parameter is filled in.

Comment: @Bee157 I believe that's what modes are for.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree

Comment: @ghost404 Please include the full source code and teh expected result, so we have an idea of what is possible and what not.

Comment: @Bee157 all code over 5k rows, so I'll include only a part of

Comment: @ghost404 Please read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your simplistic "foo/bar" example, you are saying that when a "foo" exists, you want to do some different processing for the subsequent "bar" envelopes, and don't want the other template for "bar" to apply when selecting the child elements of root.

In this case, all you would need to do is add template to the XSLT, to ignore "bar" elements if there are "foo" elements (because you know in that case the template matching "foo" is processing them with another template).

```
<xsl:template match="bar[../foo]" />
```

Now, in your actual example, the "foo" elements are "block" elements with "page" elements as children, and your "bar" elements are "block" elements with "news" elements as children. This means you only need to add this template to your existing XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="block[news][../block/page]" />
```

Or maybe this, if the "place" attribute is important

```
<xsl:template match="block[@place='main'][news][../block[@place='main']/page]" />
```

So, it there are both "page" and "news" items, this will stop the `<xsl:apply-templates />` in the "root" template processing the "news" items normally.

All your other XSLT can stay as-is, just add the above template to it, and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You should do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">            
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//foo"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="foo">
   <div>
      <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//bar" mode="inner" />
   </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
   <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar" mode="inner">
   <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template (matches /) will be executed on the root level, and the child elements will not be parsed if they are not needed. Your solution parsed everything and associated the correct templates with it.

Comment: thanks, but I unfortunately I can not use this option. I forgot to write that I already have a root template similar to the following, which I also can not change. `<xsl:template match="/root"><xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" /></xsl:template>`

Comment: @ghost404 **1.** Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead. **2.** If you cannot change the code that produces the problem, then how do you expect the problem to go away?

Comment: You could still add the `<xsl:template match="/">`

Comment: @michael.hor257k He could be using something like SAP, where he literally doesn't have rights to edit some part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="root">
<div>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo|bar">
<span>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</span>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```